# «Rückfluss» im Sinne von «Feedback»?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, anglicism

Gestolpert bin ich neulich auf [ein Dokument](https://www.grs.de/sites/default/files/pe_434_20_1_kv03endg.pdf) mit dem Wort «Rückfluss» wo man auf Neudeutsch eher «Feedback» schreiben würde:

> Neben einer Weiterentwicklung thermohydraulischer Modelle und der Ergänzung durch einen   3D-Modul   ist   deshalb   eine   konsequente   Umsetzung   neuer   Erkenntnisse,   insbesondere  aus  der  Validierung  und  dem  Rückfluss  aus  der  Anwendererfahrung,  sowie eine laufende Qualitätssicherung notwendig.

In der englischen Version wird das Wort tätsächlich mit «Feedback» übersetzt.  Bis dato hatte stand ich immer unter dem Eindruck, «Feedback» sei nicht ins Deutsche zu übersetzen und darum ein unvermeidbarer Anglizismus.

Ist «Rückfluss» im Sinne von «Feedback» gängig und gibt es andere Beispiele?  Würde man es beispielsweise im Software-Bereich verstehen?  Gibt es andere Eindeutschungen von «Feedback»?

Comment: Je nach Themengebiet kommt auch **Rückkopplung** in Frage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Zitat:** Bis dato hatte stand ich immer unter dem Eindruck, «Feedback» sei nicht ins Deutsche zu übersetzen und darum ein unvermeidbarer Anglizismus.

Da irren Sie. Für das, was Sie suchen, nämlich dass jemandem etwas sprachlich zurückgemeldet wird, gibt es schon länger den Ausdruck

> eine *Rückmeldung* geben

Im [Historischen Korpus des DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=R%C3%BCckmeldung%20&corpus=dtaxl&date-start=1473&date-end=1969&subcorpus=dingler&subcorpus=dsdk&subcorpus=dtae&subcorpus=dtak&subcorpus=gartenlaube&subcorpus=grenzboten&subcorpus=textberg_hist&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10) lässt sich *Rückmeldung* bis 1867 zurückverfolgen. Schaut man in diesem und in anderen Korpora *Feedback* nach, so stellt man fest, dass dieser Anglizismus offenbar erst Ende des 20. Jahrhunderts in Mode kam, also zu der Zeit, als auch die Kybernetik und die Informatik in Mode kamen.

*Rückfluss* und *Rückkopplung* als Übersetzung von *Feedback* kenne ich selbst nur als technische Ausdrücke im Zusammenhang mit Systemtheorie und Kybernetik. Als Synonyme für sprachliche Rückmeldung finde ich sie ungeeignet. *Rückfluss* kann man noch als Metapher verstehen (da fließen Gedankengänge an einen Gesprächspartner zurück); aber eine *Rückkopplung* ist nochmal etwas anderes: der Begriff beinhaltet den Aspekt, dass entsprechende Systeme sich unter Umständen „hochschaukeln“ können.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, *Rückmeldung* wäre mir nicht eingefallen, da eine Rückmeldung auch nach einem kurzen Antwort auf ein u. A. w. g. klingt, und man auch von *Rückmeldungen* im Mehrzahl sprechen kann, während *Feedback* fast immer ein unzählbares Substantiv ist.  Diese Beispiele bestätigen Eure Antwort: https://www.linguee.com/search?query=R%C3%BCckmeldung.