# Unterschied zwischen „Feedback“ und „Rückmeldung“

Tags: difference, anglicism

In den letzten 10 oder 20 Jahren scheint das aus dem Englischen übernommene Wort *Feedback* das deutsche Wort *Rückmeldung* immer mehr zu ersetzen. Zum Beispiel in dem Sinne, dass ein Lehrer ein Feedback von seinen Schülern über seinen Unterricht erhält (statt eine Rückmeldung).

Meine Frage ist nun, was die Bedeutungsunterschiede dieser Worte im Detail sind, oder ob sie letztlich als vollkommen synonym angesehen werden können.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass *Feedback* im deutschen Sprachgebrauch als optional und freiwillig aufgefasst wird. *Rückmeldung* ist wesentlich verpflichtender.

Comment: Verwandte Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/59284/25241

Comment: @tofro: Sehe ich nicht so. Das ist schlichtweg dasselbe.

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort *»Feedback«* hat technische Bedeutungen, die dem Wort *»Rückmeldung«* nicht so stark anhaften bzw. ganz fehlen und besser mit dem Wort *»Rückkopplung«* wiedergegeben werden:

- Wenn ein Mikrofon sein Signal an einen Verstärker schickt, der es weiter an einen Lautsprecher sendet, und wenn das Mikrofon die Töne Geräusche aufnimmt, die aus dem Lautsprecher kommen, entsteht ein lauter pfeifender Ton. Dieses Phänomen nennt man *»Feedback«* oder *»Rückkopplung«.*
- Ganz allgemein: Immer wenn ein System seinen eigenen Output wieder als Input vorgesetzt bekommt, nennt man das Feedback. Das kann verstärkend und manchmal sogar zerstörerisch wirken (Resonanzkatastrophe) oder es kann stabilisierend sein (alle Regelungssysteme arbeiten so).
- Wenn ein Computerprogramm signalisiert, dass es Eingaben auf eine bestimmte Weise verarbeitet hat, nennt man das auch *»Feedback«.* (z.B. Texte, die als Reaktion von Eingaben ausgegeben werden, Farbänderungen, Töne, usw.)

---

Anders sieht die Sache aus, wenn eine Person etwas zu einer anderen Person oder zu einer Gruppe von Menschen sagt, oder etwas vorführt, und später dann wissen will, wie seine/ihre Ansprache, Vorführung usw. bei der Zielgruppe angekommen ist. In diesem Fall sind die Wörter *»Feedback«* und *»Rückmeldung«* bedeutungsgleiche Synonyme.

Das Wort *»Feedback«* wird aber deswegen häufiger verwendet, weil im Wort *»Meldung«* und seinen Zusammensetzungen ein militärischer Unterton mitklingt. Soldaten müssen ihren Vorgesetzten gegenüber *Meldung* machen. Diese Verpflichtung klingt im Wort *»Feedback«* nicht mit. (Was aber nichts daran ändert, dass eine *»Rückmeldung«* genauso freiwillig ist wie ein *»Feedback«.*)

Etwas sehr ähnliches ist eine *»Evaluierung«,* die aber ausdrücklich verpflichtend ist. Dort wo ich unterrichte (FH St. Pölten) sind die Studierenden am Ende jeder Lehrveranstaltung verpflichtet, die Lehrbeauftragten anonym zu beurteilen. (Dazu gibt es ein eigenes Online-Tool, das die Anonymität sicherstellt.) Weil aufgrund der Anonymität nicht feststellbar ist, wer sich vor dieser Pflicht gedrückt hat, macht das nur ungefähr die Hälfte der Studierenden. Aber nichtsdestotrotz ist das eine Pflicht, die den Studierenden auferlegt ist. Hingegen ist ein Feedback (bzw. eine Rückmeldung) die freiwillige und meist nicht-anonyme Antwort auf die Frage des Vortragenden *»Wie hat Ihnen der Unterricht gefallen?«*

Comment: Beim Studium ist die *Rückmeldung* am Semesterbeginn nicht besonders freiwillig. Feedback dagegen schon.

Comment: @tofro, Ok, aber die "Rückmeldung" beim Semesterbeginn ist ein anderer Kontext als die "Rückmeldung" über die Arbeit, Leistung oder das Verhalten einer Person.

Comment: Danke für die gute und ausführliche Antwort. Das mit dem militärischen Unterton scheint mir heutzutage aber von den Leuten erheblich weniger wahrgenommen zu werden, als früher, z.B. da es keine Wehrpflicht mehr gibt und die Leute gefühlt ohnehin weniger mit Militär zu tun haben.

Comment: Zur Frage, warum "Feedback" häufiger verwendet wird, vermute ich, dass viele Leute einfach damit einfach besonders modern oder wichtig klingen wollen.

Comment: @julia Alleine die Tatsache, dass sich in meinem Beispiel *Rückmeldung* nicht durch *Feedback* ersetzen lässt, beweist ja die Bedeutungsungleichheit.

Comment: @tofro: Was genau meinst du mit *»Rückmeldung am Semesterbeginn«?* Eine Rückmeldung noch bevor es überhaupt etwas gibt, über das man eine Rückmeldung machen kann, erscheint mir höchst sinnlos zu sein. Du meinst offenbar etwas, wovon ich noch nie gehört habe (und ich habe insgesamt schon 28 Semester in fünf verschiedenen Studiengängen absolviert, und fange jetzt gerade mein sechstes Studium bzw. mein 29. Semester an).

Comment: Kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass es das in AT nicht gibt, aber vielleicht heißt es anders: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rückmeldung_(Studium)

Comment: @Julia: Ich weiß nicht, wie das im Ausland (z.B. in Deutschland) ist, aber bei uns in Österreich gibt es sehr Wohl eine Wehrpflicht. Jeder männliche Staatsbürger muss nach Erreichen der Volljährigkeit zum Bundesheer. Wahlweise kann der Dienst an der Waffe auch durch Zivildienst ersetzt werden, aber eines von beiden muss man machen (außer man erweist sich als untauglich).

Comment: @tofro: Nein, das gibt es bei uns nicht. Bei uns müssen Studierende zu Beginn des Semesters den ÖH-Beitrag bezahlen (ÖH = Österreichische Hochschülerschaft), das sind 20,20 Euro, und wer nicht an einer Uni sondern an einer FH studiert, muss zusätzlich auch die Studiengebühr zahlen (363,63 Euro, das sind nicht ganz zufällig genau 5000 Schilling in alter Währung). Aber das war's auch schon.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ja, in Deutschland ist die Wehrpflicht seit vielen Jahren ausgesetzt (seit 2011).

Comment: @Julia: Das ist ja auch noch nicht so lange her. Das heißt nämlich, dass jeder Deutsche, der heute älter als 28 ist, entweder Soldat oder Zivi (oder untauglich) war. Den militärische Beigeschmack des Wortes »Meldung« hat daher die Mehrheit der deutschen Männer selbst erfahren.

Answer (score 2):

Beide Wörter sind in der hier gemeinten Bedeutung synonym.

**[Feedback](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Feedback)**

1. Steuerung eines technischen Systems durch Rückmeldung.
2. Rückmeldung

**[Rückmeldung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/R%C3%BCckmeldung)**

1. das (Sich-)Zurückmelden
2. Feedback

---

*Rückmeldung* findet im Deutschen etwa zeitgleich mit *Feedback* größere Verbreitung und ist in der synonymen Bedeutung möglicherweise eine Lehnübersetzung des Fremdworts.

[image]

Comment: Technisch wird eigentlich eher *Rückkopplung* statt *Rückmeldung* verwendet. *Feedback* im Deutschen fast gar nicht.

Comment: Ein Diagramm ohne vernünftige Achsenbeschriftung ist Wertlos. Wichtiger noch, bei Google Ngram wird völlig außer Acht gelassen, dass *Feedback* auch ein weitverbreiteter technischer Begriff ist (Systemtheorie, Kybernetik, Informatik etc.), der als solcher in zahlreichen Fach- und Sachbüchern zu finden ist. Kurzum, Google Ngram ist kein geeignetes Werkzeug, um irgendetwas über die Verbreitung der Lexeme auszusagen. Darüber hinaus gab es *Rückmeldung* schon vor *Feedback*, es ist also keine Lehnübersetzung. Siehe etwa https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59285/25241.

Comment: @Björก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้Friedrich Ein bereits existierendes Wort kann in einer neuen Bedeutung als Lehnübersetzung eines fremdsprachlichen Begriffs verwendet werden. Deshalb habe ich auch geschrieben: "... in der synonymen Bedeutung ...". –– Wenn die Kurve der Verwendungshäufigkeit zweier Wörter, wie hier, einen parallelen Verlauf nimmt, kann man daraus schon ablesen, dass beide Begriffe in ihrer Verwendung zusammenhängen.

Comment: @user47230 - Sehr interessante Beobachtung und Hypothese; ich würde das nicht unbesehen unterschreiben, aber da kann gut 'was dran sein'.

Answer (score 0):

Ein Aspekt, der bei Hubert anklingt, aber meiner Meinung nach eine Hervorhebung verdient, ist, dass *Rückmeldung* eine verbale Komponente suggeriert oder doch zumindest eine nennenswerte Substanz.

Für den Piepser beim Strichcodeleser der Supermarktkasse passt das schlecht, ebenso bei Tastaturen, wo das fühlbare Auslösen des Tastenkontakts vor einiger Zeit noch extra mit *taktilem Feedback* beworben wurde.

Inzwischen werden von sehr vielen Geräten mehr Reaktionstypen angeboten, wie

- das kurzzeitige Invertieren einer Schaltfläche oder des ganzen Bildschirms, seit den Anfangsgründen der Rechnertechnik auch als *visual bell* bezeichnet
- das Vibrieren der virtuellen Taste auf dem Mobiltelefon
- das Aufblitzen einer Leuchtdiode beim Kartenleser, vielleicht mit einen Piepsen kombinert

Dafür erschient *Rückmeldung* als zu gewichtig. Da es in allen Fällen genau darum geht, dem Benutzer zu signalisieren, dass seine Eingabe akzeptiert wurde, ist der Begriff *Feedback* naheliegend, weil das an den auslösenden Bediener zurück geht.

Die Verwendung von *Feedback* für substantielle und verbale Rückmeldungen, wie bei der angesprochenen Lehrkraft, kann wahlweise als Modeerscheinung oder Internationalisierung des Ausdrucks verstanden werden.

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund, den Piepser eines Strichcodelesers nicht *Rückmeldung* zu nennen und würde auch sagen, dass das eine nennenswerte Substanz ist, sonst würde man es ja nicht machen. Es ist ja kein unbeabsichtigter Nebeneffekt wie etwa das Quietschen einer Bremse.